# firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default error firebase and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have this firebase error I am receiving, never seen It before. I had used stripe api / extension in connection with firebase and when i'm go to save the data in firebase db, it gives me the error firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default function

Here is my code "db.js" :

```
import getStripe from "./stripe";
import firestore from "../firebase/index"



export async function createCheckoutSession (uid){
    
    const checkout_sessionsRef =await firestore
    .collection('user')
    .doc(uid)
    .collection('checkout_sessions')
    .add({
        price : 'price_1IGEdTKDPaWWeL1ymwWH5Ubb',
        success_url :window.location.origin,
        cancel_url:window.location.origin,
    });

    checkout_sessionsRef.onSnapshot(async (snap) => {
        const {sessionId} =snap.data();
        if (sessionId ){
            const stripe = await getStripe();
            stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionId})
        }
    })
}
```

any ideas on how to fix?